# Sorting pairs of rows with tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

http://jsfiddle.net/9sKwJ/66/

```
tr.spacer { height: 40px; }
```

```
$.tablesorter.addWidget({
    id: 'spacer',
    format: function(table) {
        var c = table.config,
        $t = $(table),
        $r = $t.find('tbody').find('tr'),
        i, l, last, col, rows, spacers = [];
        if (c.sortList && c.sortList[0]) {
            $t.find('tr.spacer').removeClass('spacer');
            col = c.sortList[0][0]; // first sorted column
            rows = table.config.cache.normalized;
            last = rows[0][col]; // text from first row
            l = rows.length;
            for (i=0; i < l; i++) {
                // if text from row doesn't match last row,
                // save it to add a spacer
                if (rows[i][col] !== last) {
                    spacers.push(i-1);
                    last = rows[i][col];
                }
            }
            // add spacer class to the appropriate rows
            for (i=0; i<spacers.length; i++){
                $r.eq(spacers[i]).addClass('spacer');
            }
        }
    }
});


$('table').tablesorter({
    widgets : ['spacer']
});
```

```
<table id="test">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Another Example</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>

    <tr>
  <td>Test4</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>Hello4</td>
  </tr>          

  <tr>
  <td colspan="3">Test4</td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
  <td>Test3</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>Hello3</td>
  </tr>          

  <tr>
  <td colspan="3">Test3</td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
  <td>Test2</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>Hello2</td>
  </tr>          

  <tr>
  <td colspan="3">Test2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td>Test1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Hello1</td>
  </tr>          

  <tr>
  <td colspan="3">Test1</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This sorts just the way I want it if you sort it by the first column, but the other two columns don't maintain the same paired 'tr' sort im looking for.

Any help on this?

Comment: I updated the fiddle link incase you went to the first one, check again.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `expand-child` class name on each duplicated row:

```
<tr>
  <td>Test3</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>Hello3</td>
</tr>          

<tr class="expand-child">
  <td colspan="3">Test3</td>
</tr>
```

It's defined by the `cssChildRow` option:

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    cssChildRow: "expand-child"
});​
```

Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/9sKwJ/82/) of it in action.

Comment: Very useful. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Great. This should be an answer.